# Raspberry PI 4B [ Hardware FLow Control Failed ]

Tags: pi-4, uart

We were trying to Enable the Hardware Flow Control , but it's still causing problems for us in Raspberry Pi 4B.
we tried 5 different methods to enable the flow control at Rpi 4B as follows :

**Method-1 :**

To enable hardware control (RTS/CTS) on Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, you typically need to configure this through the serial port settings. You can achieve this using the stty command. Here's an example:

bash
stty -F /dev/ttyS0 crtscts

1. *Open Terminal:*
   Open a terminal on your Raspberry Pi. You can do this by clicking on the terminal icon in the toolbar or using a keyboard shortcut.
2. *Identify Serial Port:*
   Identify the serial port you want to configure. The default serial port on Raspberry Pi 4 is usually /dev/ttyS0. If you're using a USB-to-serial adapter, it might be something like /dev/ttyUSB0. You can use the following command to list serial devices:
   bash
   ls /dev/serial*
3. *Install Minicom (Optional):*
   You can use Minicom, a text-based serial communication program, to test the configuration. Install it if you don't have it:
   bash
   sudo apt-get install minicom
4. *Configure Serial Port:*
   Use the stty command to enable hardware flow control. For example, if you are using /dev/ttyS0:
   bash
   stty -F /dev/ttyS0 crtscts
5. *Test with Minicom (Optional):*
   If you installed Minicom, you can use it to test the serial port. Run the following command to start Minicom:
   bash
   sudo minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyS0
   Adjust the baud rate (-b) and serial port (-D) accordingly. Once in Minicom, you can send/receive data to test the hardware flow control.
6. *Make Changes Permanent (Optional):*
   If you want these changes to persist after a reboot, you can add the stty command to your startup scripts. For example, you can add it to the end of the /etc/rc.local file:
   bash
   sudo nano /etc/rc.local
   Add the following line before exit 0:
   bash
   stty -F /dev/ttyS0 crtscts
7. *Reboot:*
   Reboot your Raspberry Pi to apply the changes:
   bash
   sudo reboot

**Method 2 :**

If the previous steps didn't work for you, you might want to try an alternative method by modifying the /boot/config.txt file. Here are the steps:

1. Open the /boot/config.txt file for editing:
   bash
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt
2. Add the following line at the end of the file:
   plaintext
   enable_uart=1
3. Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. Reboot your Raspberry Pi:
   bash
   sudo reboot

**Method-3**
I apologize for any inconvenience. Let's try another approach. Instead of using the mini UART, we can configure the hardware UART (UART0) to enable hardware flow control (RTS/CTS).

1. Open the /boot/config.txt file for editing:
   bash
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt
2. Add or modify the following lines to enable the hardware UART and specify the GPIO pins for RTS and CTS:
   plaintext
   enable_uart=1
   dtoverlay=uart0,cts_pin=18,rts_pin=17

   Make sure to adjust the GPIO pin numbers (17 and 18 in this example) based on your specific setup. These GPIO pins are just placeholders; choose pins that are suitable for your project.
3. Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. Reboot your Raspberry Pi:
   bash
   sudo reboot

Method-4
I'm sorry to hear that the previous suggestions haven't resolved the issue. Another approach you can try is using the gpio-ctsdtr overlay. Here's how you can do it:

1. Open the /boot/config.txt file for editing:
   bash
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt
2. Add the following lines at the end of the file:
   plaintext
   enable_uart=1
   dtoverlay=gpio-ctsdtr
3. Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. Reboot your Raspberry Pi:
   bash
   sudo reboot

**Method-5**
I'm sorry to hear that the previous suggestions didn't work for you. As a last troubleshooting step, you might want to try disabling the serial console, as it can interfere with the UART settings.

1. Open the /boot/cmdline.txt file for editing:
   bash
   sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt
2. Remove the part that references the serial console. It typically looks like:
   plaintext
   console=serial0,115200

   After removing it, the line might look something like:
   plaintext
   console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=...
3. Save the file and exit the text editor.
4. Reboot your Raspberry Pi:
   bash
   sudo reboot

So logically when after trying these methods when RTS-CTS pins are connected physically only the message flow should happen right.
But without Connecting these Lines also we are to See the message flow happening and to Double check as a CTS and RTS pins are active-low we have forcefully connected to 3.3V but still data flow is happening .
which means Hardware flow control not enabled.

Please share your suggestions.

Comment: I see no test code or diagnostic output. You appear to have posted a conversation with an unknown participant.

Comment: looks like a session with ShatGPT

Comment: Are you including the word `plaintext` when you edit the files ShatGPT is telling you to edit? don't

Comment: Hi 
1. you are correct its GPT session because we couldn't find any proper documentation related to this ,
 Even we checked some git repo's where same issue was reported but no conclusion was there , so we thought to get compiled data from GPT . 
2. Reason why we didnt posted any test code or output because we were trying directly with proprietary code .

can you suggest some good documentation for HW flow control ? or in any ticket where same issue was reported and was resolved , 
also any suggestion for test scenario or test code to test flow control .